# Splitting sentences but still keeping the delimeters?

Tags: python, string, split

**AXIS 2/4 amount transferred from AXIS current account to TERM LOAN account current account**

for the above example I need an output like this:

> > python (some method for splitting sentence using **TO** keyword)

```
Output : [AXIS 2/4 amount transferred from AXIS current account] [to TERM LOAN account current account]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string with the split() function and then append the "to" string to the last element.

Here is a snippet:

```
my_string = "AXIS 2/4 amount transferred from AXIS current account to TERM LOAN account current account"
my_result = my_string.split("to")
my_result[-1] = "to "+my_result[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to split, just find the index of `to` and take the slices.

```py
text ="AXIS 2/4 amount transferred from AXIS current account to TERM LOAN account current account"

[text[:text.find('to')], text[text.find('to'):]]

#output 
['AXIS 2/4 amount transferred from AXIS current account ', 'to TERM LOAN account current account']
```